# Changing the symbology of a .geojson file in QGIS, through the Python console

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, symbology, qgsvectorlayer

I have tried to look through the PyQGIS developer cookbook and change the symbology of a point file to a black circle but unfortunately every time I add it, the symbology does not change. It should just be a simple process but it does not seem to work. The first line of code I have written so far adds the .geojson file to the project and the second one aims to change the symbology:

```
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer("path_to_.geojsonfile", "Earthquake Event: ", "ogr")
if not vlayer:
    print("Layer failed to load!")

symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol.createSimple({'name': 'circle', 'color': 'black'})
layer.renderer().setSymbol(symbol)
# show the change
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `layer.renderer()` and `layer.triggerRepaint()` which are incorrect. It should be `vlayer.renderer()` and `vlayer.triggerRepaint()`.

Notice the `v` before `layer.renderer()` and `layer.triggerRepaint()`.

You need to choose whether to remove `v` from `vlayer` variable when adding the vector layer, or add `v` to the variable when calling `.renderer()` and `.triggerRepaint()` methods.

Here is a working code

```
vlayer = iface.addVectorLayer("path_to_.geojsonfile", "Earthquake Event: ", "ogr")
if not vlayer:
    print("Layer failed to load!")

symbol = QgsMarkerSymbol.createSimple({'name': 'circle', 'color': 'black'})
vlayer.renderer().setSymbol(symbol)
# show the change
vlayer.triggerRepaint()
```

Here is the output:

[image]